# Android Emulator not starting

Tags: linux, android-emulator, emulators

Using Ubuntu 15.10 I am not able to emulate an Android device using any x86 images.

The emulator starts but the screen stays black. Using an ARM image works.

From what I found it seems to  be related to some 32Bit libraries missing. But I was not able to locate the missing once.

The log looks like this:

```
/home/christian/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Comment: Did you try re installing HAXM?

Comment: In the SKD-Manager HAXM is listed as not compatible with Linux.

Comment: you can try this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) out..

Comment: It fails on the step
    `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch` saying: `E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch`

Comment: Ignoring the multiarch problem and just continuing with the guide I get this output trying to start a emulator: `/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library [lib64OpenglRender]: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.`